# Контроль за dotnet core worker

Tags: rest, .net-core, backgroundworker

Есть долгоиграющая задача, которая может выполняться несколько часов. Необходимо её запускать по требованию и контролировать ход работы. Как это сделать, например, в консольном приложении через `Task` и `Channels` я знаю. Но как сделать подобное в `.net core web api`? Я только начал осваивать, потому вопросы могут показаться детскими.

По отдельности, `Rest Api` или запустить `worker` я могу. Но как всё это совместить? И как контролировать работу воркера?

Я правильно понимаю, что суть `Rest Api`, не держать пользователя в ожидании, а выполнить работу и вернуть результат? Но тогда как проверить, что воркер завершил свою работу? В интернете, все примеры идут либо про `Rest Api`, либо про `BackgroundWorker`

Comment: Мысли таковы: 1) Запрос, который запускает задачу вашу. 2) На клиенте можете показать что задача начала выпоняться. На сервере записываете куда-нибудь текущий результат (БД или сесия или еще что-то). 3) Отображение на клиенте можно сделать по разному: например 1. Поднять сокет и отдавать только если (к примеру результат поменялся) 2. Сделать на сервере функцию, которая бы показало записанное значение по запросу, и слать этот запрос по какому-то интервалу. 3. - Возможно вам что то еще предложат, пока это все что в голову пришло

Comment: Логика понятная, больше интересуют технические аспекты. Совсем не хочется велосипед изобретать.